# I want every printed paper has my name and contact number on it

Tags: windows, gratis, printing

My old PC is running XP SP3 and connected to HP OfficeJect 4620 printer.
I have to make 50 copies of a document for my classmates. 
The problem is that I was told to write my name and contact number on each copy, which I think will make me exhausted.
Could you recommend me any software that will help me solve this problem?

Comment: What is the document format of the source file? Can you edit it?

Comment: Some printer drivers allow for placing a watermark. Maybe you could provide your own "watermark" here to match your needs.

Comment: Print once, write by hand, make 49 photocopies?

Comment: Why don't you just add your contact details in the footer of the document?

Answer (score 3):

If you are scanning the document then scan to PDF and then use [PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) free server command line tool to add a [stamp](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-stamp) with your contact details.

If you already have the document in a word processor format you would be better off just adding a header with the same details.

Then just print out your document.

Alternatively you may be able to add a watermark via your printers settings dialog, (usually on the advanced tab), or for a really basic method - work out how many pages you are talking about and print just your name and contact details near the edge of every page then re-use the paper to print the documents.

For a real out of the box answer just get or make a rubber stamp and use that with an ink pad ...